# How do I subset a dataframe's columns if the data is all the same?

Tags: r, filter, subset, unique

I have a really large dataset and I want to filter out some of the columns because it is the same data all throughout (ex: company name is all "Walmart"). I can go through and do these manually but I'm looking for a code to do it automatically.

I had in mind a function to subset based on if sum(unique(colnam)) == 1 but not sure how to get it to work. Thanks.

Comment: Can you share reproducible example using dput() function?

Answer (score 0):

```
which(sapply(dat, function(col)  length(unique(col)) == 1))
```

Comment: Please search before answering.